# WCF System.IndexOutOfRangeException in Dispatcher.DispatchOperationRuntime.InspectInputsCore

Tags: wcf

**Issue:** Getting below error while WCF service is invoked.

Index was outside the bounds of the array.
               at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.DispatchOperationRuntime.InspectInputsCore(MessageRpc& rpc)
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.DispatchOperationRuntime.InvokeBegin(MessageRpc& rpc)
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage5(MessageRpc& rpc)
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage4(MessageRpc& rpc)
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.MessageRpc.Process(Boolean isOperationContextSet)
               System.IndexOutOfRangeException

Need help to resolve this issue.

**Details:**
We have web-hosted (in same virtual directory, ASP.NET compatiblity enabled, baic http binding) multiple WCF services created as below

6 Services with individual service contracts for each service and respective datacontracts for each operations. Uses custom service host factory which adds a Message Inspector

2 services hosted in below fashion
2 seperate wsdls (design time files, with different schemas) pointing to the same service endpoint implementing the below contract. Uses a different custom service host factory which also adds a Message Inspector

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IGenericService
{
    [OperationContract(Action = "*", ReplyAction = "*")]
    System.ServiceModel.Channels.Message GenericOperation(System.ServiceModel.Channels.Message msgRequest);
}

[ServiceBehavior(InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.PerCall,
    ValidateMustUnderstand = false)]
[AspNetCompatibilityRequirements(RequirementsMode = AspNetCompatibilityRequirementsMode.Allowed)]
public class GenericService : IGenericService
{
    public Message GenericOperation(Message msgRequest)
    {
```

All of these services are having proxies in SOA platform (Progress Actional). Actional maintains the direct endpoints for invoking the actual service and is able to properly invoke the actual service.

All 8 services are working fine in a server used for UnitTest execution. When deployed to QA servers all 6 services with individual service contracts work fine but the 2 new services (design time wsdls files) thow error listed above.

Code inside MessageInspector (failing services) looks as below. Other Inspector for other set of 6 services is similar.

```
public object AfterReceiveRequest(ref System.ServiceModel.Channels.Message request, System.ServiceModel.IClientChannel channel, System.ServiceModel.InstanceContext instanceContext)
    {
        return Stopwatch.StartNew();
    }

    public void BeforeSendReply(ref System.ServiceModel.Channels.Message reply, object correlationState)
    {
        Stopwatch watch = (Stopwatch)correlationState;
        watch.Stop();
        TimeSpan performanceTime = watch.Elapsed;
        watch = null;
            // Invoke Performance Logging Code
       }
    }
```

ServiceTrace looks as below.

Construct ServiceHost 'XyzServices.SpecificService' (One of the 6 service with individual service contract)

**Open ServiceHost 'XyzServices.SpecificService'**

*All Endpoint listner opened for specific service*

**Listen at 'specificservice uri'

Processing message 1

Process action 'SpecificService.SpecificOperation.SoapAction'

Execute 'XyzServices.SpecificService.SpecificOperation'

Construct ServiceHost 'XyzServices.GenericService'

Processing message 2**

> From: Listen at 'XyzServices.SpecificService endpoint' 
>   Activity boundary Start
>   To: Process action 'GenericService.GenericOperation.SoapAction'
>   To: Listen at 'XyzServices.SpecificService endpoint'
>   Activity boundary Stop

**Open ServiceHost 'XyzServices.GenericService'**

> *All Endpoint listner opened for Generic service*

**Process action 'GenericService.GenericOperation.SoapAction'**

> *From: Processing message 2
>
>   Activity boundary Start
>
>   Received message over channel* - Message header looks fine. Does not show message body
>   *ServiceChannel information* - Every thing looks fine here for (Unit Test server and QA server)
>   ***Handling an exception*** - shows the exception pasted in question details (only in QA server)
>   *Sent a message over a channel
>
>   Aborted InstanceContext
>
>   Activity boundary Stop*
>   (This activity looks fine when services run in Unit test server)

I used service trace viewer for the first time, but I noted that 'Processing message 2' activity starts from a activity which is related with the specific service. Does that indicate any problem in the way services are hosted. (where these services need separation)
Please let me know, if more details are needed.

```
this.InitializeCallContext(ref rpc); 
                object target = rpc.Instance;  
                this.DeserializeInputs(ref rpc);  
                **this.InspectInputs(ref rpc);** 

                ValidateMustUnderstand(ref rpc); 

                IAsyncResult result = null; 
                IDisposable impersonationContext = null;  
                IPrincipal originalPrincipal = null; 
                bool isThreadPrincipalSet = false;  

                try
                {  
                    if (this.parent.SecurityImpersonation != null) 
                    { 
                        this.parent.SecurityImpersonation.StartImpersonation(ref rpc, out impersonationContext, out originalPrincipal, out isThreadPrincipalSet); 
                    }

void InspectInputsCore(ref MessageRpc rpc) 
    {  
        int offset = this.Parent.ParameterInspectorCorrelationOffset; 

        for (int i = 0; i < this.ParameterInspectors.Length; i++) 
        {  
            IParameterInspector inspector = this.ParameterInspectors[i]; 
            rpc.Correlation[offset + i] = inspector.BeforeCall(this.Name, rpc.InputParameters);  
        }  
    }
```

Comment: Given that the issue appears to be the MessageInspector, posting the code for it would probably be more relevant than the services themselves.

Comment: Thanks for looking into this Tim. I have pasted the code inside inspectors above.

Comment: As I don't see any arrays, it's likely that the error occurs in "// Invoke Performance Logging Code"

Comment: Thanks! I just added the traces to question. The traces don't show that GenericService.GenericOperation is invoked at all. So this error happens even before it is invoked. And logging is done in BeforeReply.

Comment: try putting more logging to determine which line of code is failing.  Seems like its throwing the exception in a behaviour so its not hitting the service yet.  Are there any more behaviours?

Comment: Thank! I wrote below items to logs inside 'AfterReceiveRequest'. `instanceContext.GetServiceInstance().GetType().ToString(). This is written as XyzServices.GenericService `instanceContext.Host.GetType().ToString(). This is written as XyzServices.GenericServiceHost Both looked fine. Please let me know, if there are other details that can be written to logs to identify the rootcause. Also any other WCF extensibility points where I can extract other diagnostic details.

Comment: No There are no other behaviors implemented.

Comment: As per below link
[link] http://reflector.webtropy.com/default.aspx/WCF/WCF/3@5@30729@1/untmp/Orcas/SP/ndp/cdf/src/WCF/ServiceModel/System/ServiceModel/Dispatcher/DispatchOperationRuntime@cs/3/DispatchOperationRuntime@cs
I have pasted the code snippet from this link in original question.

Comment: The exception is actually thrown from 'InspectInputsCore()' which is being called by 'InspectInputs'. This loops for ParameterInspectors and this is where it errors out. Need help to identify scenario where this loop cause IndexOutOfRange exception

Comment: I implemented a ParameterInspector and got reference to the DispatchOperation. Wrote a Loop for each ParameterInspectors for the operation. I found there was one more parameter inspector being present in the behavior `Actional.WCF.Inspectors.ServerCallInspector`